# Hourly Summary Report

Tags: regex

I've got a list of items on an hourly basis but they don't happen every hour so I have holes in my list. I've also got a blank template for every hour but any sort of diff tools won't match up the lines with the same time and date.  How can I fill in my list to have the empty hours? I was thinking something along the lines of a regex match up to the count and replace the 0 in the template with the count.

```
Counted List
4/1/2014,4:00 PM,5
4/1/2014,6:00 PM,3
4/1/2014,7:00 PM,4
4/1/2014,9:00 PM,5
4/1/2014,10:00 PM,4
4/2/2014,7:00 AM,3
4/2/2014,8:00 AM,3

Template
4/1/2014,12:00 AM,0
4/1/2014,1:00 AM,0
4/1/2014,2:00 AM,0
4/1/2014,3:00 AM,0
4/1/2014,4:00 AM,0
```

Comment: What language? This is not the best example for regex; it would be better to split by newlines, loop through each date, and add in the missing dates. Regex "matches" instead of "counting" or "comparing", so it doesn't make sense to try to force it to.

Comment: One time deal so I can do it in anything. I was thinking regex to match the time and date and capture over the counted list and anything that doesn't match would stay as 0.

Comment: Okay, regex may help (to find the date/time/count) but I think it would be easiest to do primarily with the help of another language. I'll whip something up in PHP.

Comment: Awesome, i'm not normally the reports guy and I could think of a few ways to do it but they all seemed quite elaborate for the one time I get stuck doing this.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP:**

```
$regex = '~(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}),(\d{1,2}:00 [AP]M),(\d+)~';
$oneHour = new DateInterval('PT1H');

$lines = explode("\n", $data);
$count = count($lines);

$final = array();
foreach($lines as $key => $line) {
    preg_match($regex, $line, $currentMatches);
    $final[] = $currentMatches[0];
    
    if($key < $count - 1) {
        preg_match($regex, $lines[$key + 1], $nextMatches);
        
        $currentDate = new DateTime($currentMatches[1] . ' ' . $currentMatches[2]);
        $nextDate = new DateTime($nextMatches[1] . ' ' . $nextMatches[2]);
        
        while($nextDate->getTimestamp() - $currentDate->getTimestamp() != 60 * 60) {
            $currentDate = $currentDate->add($oneHour);
            $final[] = $currentDate->format('n/j/Y,g:i A,0');
        }
    }
}
$data = implode("\n", $final);
```

**Output (using your input as $data):**

```
4/1/2014,4:00 PM,5
4/1/2014,5:00 PM,0
4/1/2014,6:00 PM,3
4/1/2014,7:00 PM,4
4/1/2014,8:00 PM,0
4/1/2014,9:00 PM,5
4/1/2014,10:00 PM,4
4/1/2014,11:00 PM,0
4/2/2014,12:00 AM,0
4/2/2014,1:00 AM,0
4/2/2014,2:00 AM,0
4/2/2014,3:00 AM,0
4/2/2014,4:00 AM,0
4/2/2014,5:00 AM,0
4/2/2014,6:00 AM,0
4/2/2014,7:00 AM,3
4/2/2014,8:00 AM,3
```

---

**Explanation:**

First off, `$data` is your input data (from a file?) that contains the date/time/count strings delimited by new lines.  Then we use the expression [`$regex = '~(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}),(\d{1,2}:00 [AP]M),(\d+)`](http://regex101.com/r/lT5mR5) which assumes your data is ALWAYS in the format `mm/dd/YYYY,hh:00 XM,#`.  The big note here is, based on your example, we don't care about minutes at all and are really strict on the format.

Also, we ***assume*** that every single line will match our regular expression.  If it doesn't, you'll need to add some conditionals in here.  We first match our current line and add it to a new array.  Then, if we aren't at the end of the array, we match the next line.  Now we compare these dates, and loop through `while` the next date isn't 1 hour in the future from the current date.  We update the current date, add a placeholder with a count of 0 to the new array, and then stop when the next date is an hour in the future.  We will pick up with this line in the next iteration of our `foreach`.

---

**Links:**

- [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match)
- [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)
- [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [`DateTime::diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)
- [`DateTime::getTimestamp()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)
- [`DateTime::add()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)
- [`DateTime::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)